# Group dictionaries with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, collections

I have two `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> ListdicA = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic1.Add("Type1", "1");
dic1.Add("Type2", "A");
dic1.Add("Type3", "X");
Dictionary<string, string> dic2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic2.Add("Type1", "2");
dic2.Add("Type2", "B");
dic2.Add("Type3", "Y");
ListdicA.Add(dic1);
ListdicA.Add(dic2);

List<Dictionary<string, string>> ListdicB = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> dic3 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic3.Add("Type1", "1");
dic3.Add("Type2", "C");
dic3.Add("Type3", "X");
Dictionary<string, string> dic4 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic4.Add("Type1", "2");
dic4.Add("Type2", "D");
dic4.Add("Type3", "Z");
ListdicB.Add(dic3);
ListdicB.Add(dic4);
```

---

I want to merge the two lists and group the values by their keys. The result is a `List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>`. First, I want to merge the two lists:

```
Type1 1
Type2 A
Type3 X

Type1 2
Type2 B
Type3 Y

Type1 1
Type2 C
Type3 X

Type1 2
Type2 D
Type3 Z
```

And I want group it by the keys, the result look like:

```
Type1 1
Type2 A C
Type3 X X

Type1 2
Type2 B D
Type3 Y Z
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logical conditions for grouping. Could you modify your question to include details on how the different groupings should be done ?

Comment: I want  to merge two List and grouping it by Type1 @Luc Morin

Comment: You need to join the keys of the two dictionary using a outer join since you need to include all keys of both dictionaries.  See following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Why `X X` (while you don't have `1 1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on Question Update:**

This is very complex (at least it was for me). I showed the steps and also i put each LINQ inside parenthesis which do the part of that job.

1) You have to join two lists. (`ListdicA.Concat(ListdicB)`)

2) Group all Dictionaries by Value of `Type1` key in each dictionaries.(`GroupBy(x => x["Type1"])`)

3) Unwrap all Items `IGrouping<string,Dictionary<string,string>>` to `KeyValuePair<string,string>` (`SelectMany(y => y)`)

4) Again Group key value pairs by Key so that you join values of same keys together  (`GroupBy(y => y.Key)`)

5) Unwrap `IGrouping<string,KeyValuePair<string,string>>` into `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>>` (`Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(y.Key, y.Select(z => z.Value).ToList()))`)

6) Convert `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>>>` into `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,List<string>>>` (`Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value))`)

7) Finally Convert `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,List<string>>>` into `List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>` (`ToList()`)

```
string groupby = "Type1";

List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> result =
    ListdicA.Concat(ListdicB).GroupBy(x => x[groupby]).Select(x =>
        x.SelectMany(y => y) // Put .Distinct() here to remove duplicates.(optional)
            .GroupBy(y => y.Key).Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(y.Key, y.Select(z => z.Value).ToList())))
                .Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value)).ToList();

foreach (var d in result)
{
    foreach (var k in d)
    {
        Console.Write(k.Key + " : ");
        foreach (var l in k.Value)
        {
            Console.Write(l + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
Type1 1 1
Type2 A C
Type3 X X

Type1 2 2
Type2 B D
Type3 Y Z
```

As I noted in comment (inside code) if you remove that comment and put `.Distinct()` right there it will remove duplicates

```
List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> result =
    ListdicA.Concat(ListdicB).GroupBy(x => x[groupby]).Select(x => x.SelectMany(y => y)
        .Distinct().GroupBy(y => y.Key)
            .Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(y.Key, y.Select(z => z.Value).ToList())))
                .Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value)).ToList();
```

will output.

```
Type1 1
Type2 A C
Type3 X

Type1 2
Type2 B D
Type3 Y Z
```

If you dont want to loose `X` then you need a custom Distinct. You will need this class. ([linq was taken and edited from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/489421/4767498))

```
public static class SomeMoreLinq
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctIf<TSource>
        (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TSource> seenKeys = new HashSet<TSource>();
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (seenKeys.Add(element) || !keySelector(element))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it in your query.

```
List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> result =
    ListdicA.Concat(ListdicB).GroupBy(x => x[groupby]).Select( x => x.SelectMany(y => y)
        .DistinctIf(y => y.Key == groupby).GroupBy(y => y.Key)
            .Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(y.Key, y.Select(z => z.Value).ToList())))
                .Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value)).ToList();
```

will output.

```
Type1 1
Type2 A C
Type3 X X

Type1 2
Type2 B D
Type3 Y Z
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

While this completely melted my mind but it was a good practice!.

Comment: Thanks you so much, but I want the result is List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>, isn't Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Comment: can you explain more about your logic? your output seems to be completely wrong. please update your question and fix your output. @VũBích

Comment: I don’t know how to express my thanks! That exactly what I want to do <3 <3  @M.kazem Akhgary

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
ListdicA.Zip(ListdicB, (a,b) => a.Concat(b)
.GroupBy(x => x.Key)
.Select (g => new
              {
                   g.Key, 
                   Values = g.SelectMany(d => d.Value).Distinct()
              } ))
```

you get this result:

```
Type 1   1
Type 2   A
         C
Type 3   X

Type 1   2
Type 2   B
         D
Type 3   Y
         Z
```

I'm not sure whether your `X X` result is deliberate, or a typo. If it's intended I should add some more logic.